# How to align icon and text inside the big button?

Tags: javafx-2

I have quite a big button (`minWidth` and `minHeight` were explicitly set to big numbers), and inside that big button there is relatively small icon and some text. Icon and text do not consume all available space, and end up being placed in the center of the button.

I want to put icon and text to the left side of the button. But it seems that I do not understand what all those alignments mean, since setting `alignment` to `BASELINE_LEFT` or setting `textAlignment` to `LEFT` didn't change anything.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Property `textAlignment` controls alignment for multiline text so it wouldn't help you.

But both

```
 btn.setStyle("-fx-alignment: LEFT;");
```

or

```
 btn.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
```

should work for you. See example below.

[image]

```
public class ILoveBigButtonsAndICannotLie extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Button");
        btn.setGraphic(new Rectangle(10,10, Color.RED));
        btn.setMinHeight(200);
        btn.setMinWidth(250);
        //btn.setStyle("-fx-alignment: LEFT;");
        btn.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely correct - it seems that there are some problems with ScalaFX wrapper. It was setting alignment via `getProperties.put("alignment", a)`.

Comment: It's been a while, but would anyone by chance know how to align only the icon to the left?